# SNS Heatmap, display one column label out of two

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I am currently working on the dataset: Car_Price_Assignment (Kaggle).

When I display my correlation heatmap, with only the 'price' column (x-axis), it displays only one label out of two in y_axis (see below).

Here is my code:

```
sns.heatmap(dataset.corr()[['price']], cbar=True, annot=True, cmap='RdBu', fmt='.2f');

fig= plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(4,10)
plt.show()
```

Thank you in advance for your insights :) !!

Display each label in y_axis.

[My current heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xow8e.png)

Comment: You could try `df = dataset.corr()[['price']]` and then `sns.heatmap(df, yticklabels=df.index, ....)`.  Also, it makes sense to create the figure before calling `sns.heatmap`, e.g. `fig = plt.figure(figsize_=...)`.  You might want to add a link to the dataset at Kaggle to make it easier for other to reproduce your plot. Are you using the latest seaborn version?

Comment: Your solution works perfectly ! Thank you ! 

Here my code :

`df = dataset.corr()[['price']]

sns.heatmap(data=df, yticklabels=df.index, cbar=True, annot=True, cmap='RdBu', fmt='.2f');

fig= plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(4,10)
plt.show()`

Comment: It is really recommended to first create the figure instead of afterwards changing its size.  Matplotlib takes the current `figsize` into account to make decisions about ticks. By the way, I just noticed that `sns.heatmap(... yticklabels=True)` also works, and is more general. By default, `yticklabels='auto'` which lets seaborn make some educated guesses about how many labels you want.

Comment: Thanks for this information, it's worth noting!